# Retrieve a positive or a negative angle from 3 points

Tags: c#, math, rotation, point, angle

I am rotating points around a center point in 2D space.  The points are the center point, the old mouse position, and the new mouse position.  My rotation function works fine, and I can calculate the angle perfectly.  But I want to calculate a negative angle if the user is moving their mouse in a direction which should be interpreted as counter-clockwise.

For example, moving the mouse toward the right (positive x-axis) should rotate clockwise if you are above (less than) the y value of the center point, but it should rotate counter-clockwise if you are actually below (greater than) the y value of the center point.

Here's what I have:

```
PointF centerPoint;
PointF oldPoint;
PointF newPoint;

double Xc = centerPoint.X;
double Yc = centerPoint.Y;
double Xb = oldPoint.X;
double Yb = oldPoint.Y;
double Xa = newPoint.X;
double Ya = newPoint.Y;

double c2 = (Math.Pow(Xb - Xa, 2) + Math.Pow(Yb - Ya, 2));
double a2 = (Math.Pow(Xb - Xc, 2) + Math.Pow(Yb - Yc, 2));
double b2 = (Math.Pow(Xa - Xc, 2) + Math.Pow(Ya - Yc, 2));

double a = Math.Sqrt(a2);
double b = Math.Sqrt(b2);

double val = (a2 + b2 - c2) / (2 * a * b);
double angle = Math.Acos(val);
```

So I need a way to make angle negative when it needs to be, so the points rotate clockwise or counter-clockwise to follow the mouse position.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, but I'm not sure:

```
double v1x = Xb - Xc;
double v1y = Yb - Yc;
double v2x = Xa - Xc;
double v2y = Ya - Yc;

double angle = Math.Atan2(v1x, v1y) - Math.Atan2(v2x, v2y);
```

Comment: This seems to work.  It goes counter-clockwise when it is supposed to.

Answer (score 3):

```
private double AngleFrom3PointsInDegrees(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3)
{
    double a = x2 - x1;
    double b = y2 - y1;
    double c = x3 - x2;
    double d = y3 - y2;

    double atanA = Math.Atan2(a, b);
    double atanB = Math.Atan2(c, d);

    return (atanA - atanB) * (-180 / Math.PI); 
    // if Second line is counterclockwise from 1st line angle is 
    // positive, else negative
}
```

Comment: i had to add negative X values to get it to work for me (the calculations now match AutoCAD)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all you need to do is

```
angle = angle > Math.PI ? angle - 2*Math.PI : angle;
```

at the end of your code.  That will give you a clockwise rotation to the right of the line defined by centerPoint and oldPoint, and counter-clockwise to the left of it, regardless of orientation.

Comment: angle is never greater than Math.PI.

Comment: Hmmm.  You may need to reformulate your angle calculation to take use Math.atan2(), so that you get an angle in the correct quadrant.

Answer (score 0):

Given vectors (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), I would suggest computing the cross product and dot product, and then using Atan2() on them.  That will work in all cases where both vectors are non-zero and vector lengths are "reasonable".