# Retrieve a positive or a negative angle from 3 points on circle

Tags: c#, geometry

I have 3 points and X,Y coordinates for all 3

- One of the points is center of circle
- The two other points are moving on this circle

I am trying to find direction of moving clock or clockwise I tried using vector and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022563/retrieve-a-positive-or-a-negative-angle-from-3-points).

I always get angle positive on this coordinates:

- clock from P1>>>>>> p2
  center (-1.236,6.937)
  P1 (1113.749,3070.335)
  P2 (2094.251,2504.242)
- clockwise P3>>>>P4
  center (-1.236,6.937)
  P3 (2479.926,1439.437)
  P4 (1988.959,2067.846)

  ```
  public static double AngleFrom3PointsInDegrees(double Xc, double Yc, double Xa, double Ya, double Xb, double Yb)
  {
    /*  double Xc = centerPoint.X;
      double Yc = centerPoint.Y;
      double Xb = oldPoint.X;
      double Yb = oldPoint.Y;
      double Xa = newPoint.X;
      double Ya = newPoint.Y;
      */
      double c2 = (Math.Pow(Xb - Xa, 2) + Math.Pow(Yb - Ya, 2));
      double a2 = (Math.Pow(Xb - Xc, 2) + Math.Pow(Yb - Yc, 2));
      double b2 = (Math.Pow(Xa - Xc, 2) + Math.Pow(Ya - Yc, 2));

      double a = Math.Sqrt(a2);
      double b = Math.Sqrt(b2);

      double val = (a2 + b2 - c2) / (2 * a * b);
      double angle = Math.Acos(val);
     return angle = angle > Math.PI ? angle - 2 * Math.PI : angle;
  }
  public Form1()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     double Case1= AngleFrom3PointsInDegrees(-1.236,6.937,1113.749,3070.335,2094.251,2504.242);
     double Case2 = AngleFrom3PointsInDegrees(-1.236, 6.937, 247.926, 1439.437, 1988.959, 2067.846);
     MessageBox.Show("Angle = " + Case1);
      MessageBox.Show("Angle = " + Case2);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Let's center point is (xc,yc) and two points on circle are (xa,ya) and (xb,yb), so vectors

```
CA = (xa-xc, ya-yc), CB = (xb-xc, yb-yc)
```

then signed angle between these vectors is

```
Angle = atan2(VectorProduct(CA, CB), ScalarProduct(CA, CB))  = 
        atan2(CA.x*CB.y-CA.y*CB.x, CA.x*CB.x+CA.y*CB.y)
```